# Error while using regex function

Tags: regex, r

I have a text object that I would like to extract only consecutive words that begin with capital letters (for example , John Rye).I tried to use regmatches() and gregexpr() but I get an error.How can I solve this issue?

```
txt<-"This is John Rye walking."

regmatches(txt, gregexpr('(.*)\s(.*)', txt, perl=T))[[1]]
Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'(.*)\s"
```

I also tried:

```
regmatches(txt, gregexpr('(^[A-Z][-a-zA-Z]+$)', txt, perl=T))[[1]]
```

but got this result:

```
character(0)
```

Comment: The point is that you need to double the backslashes with ``\\s``.

Comment: Try `regmatches(txt, gregexpr('\\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*', txt))[[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` and `$` are the begin/end of the string anchors, you probably confused them with word boundaries (`\b`, `\\b` if escaped). `-` doesn't look like something appropriate at all.

So, the regex should be changed to

```
\\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\\b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . How can I make sure to get only two words that have first letter in caps lock like : "Jhon Rye" ?

Comment: Note that you do not need the final `\\b` and the `+` at the end will not allow extracting 1 letter words. Maybe the latter is ok

Comment: @mql Which two, exactly?

Comment: @Wiktor Omitting `\b` at the end would lead to something like `John123` being accepted. Not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: `"(?<!\\S)[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*(?!\\S)"`

Comment: @mql I get it, but what's the logic behind picking two words out of three? (`This, John, Rye`)

Comment: I'm going to use a dictionary later to extract only phrases that i need

Comment: @nicael, how can i extract the two word together?.

Comment: @mql Ah, do you mean just consecutive words beginning with capital letters?

Comment: @mql `(\\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\\b ?){2}` should help you.

Comment: regmatches(txt, gregexpr('\\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\\b?{2}', txt))[[1]]
[1] "This" "John" "Rye" but there is an "is" between "This" and "John"

Comment: @mql Nope, you forgot brackets. Look closer at my comment.

Comment: @nicael, thank you. regmatches(txt, gregexpr('(\\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\\b ?){2}', txt))[[1]] works!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job as well :

```
 txt<-"This is John Rye walking."
 regmatches(txt, gregexpr('(([A-Z])\\w+\\b ){2}', txt))[[1]]
 [1] "John Rye "
```